# Error in AJAX post when running from local web server but not local file system

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get, same-origin-policy

I have a website that works fine when I am running it locally off of the file system, but when I try to run the same site using a local web server it breaks.  If I use a **post** I get a **405 Method Not Allowed** error.  If I use a **get** call then I receive **404 Not Found**.

What I think:  It has something to do with the Same Origin Policy, I have sen similar questions, but have not been able to get my code working using those answers.

The website is all HTML and JavaScript, I am using IIS 7.5 as my web server. I am also using the jQuery 1.9 library to make the AJAX calls. The call and its contents are posted below(in the post version).

```
$.get('js/questionJSON.json', function(data){       

    var template = $('#optionTemplate').html();
    var li = $('#templateLI').html();
    var partials = {"templateLI": li}
    var html = Mustache.render(template,data, partials);        
    $('#questionHolder').append(html);
    $('#sortable li .destroyer').click(destroyer);
    $('#sortable li .correctnessGauge').click(correctnessChanger);      
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
    $('#adder').click(createNewListItem);
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(changeMenuText);
    $('#ready2GoBtn').click(createQJSON);
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        handle: ".handler",
        create: numberItems,
        stop: numberItems
    });         
},'json');
```

Also here are the headers

**Response Headers**

```
  Cache-Control private
Content-Length  7265
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 10 Jul 2013 19:39:57 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

**Request Headers**

```
         Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    192.168.200.175:90
Referer http://192.168.200.175:90/multi_choice.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

I know close to nothing about web servers, so if the answer to my question would be best explained by some reference resource I would also appreciate a pointer to that.

Comment: Your webserver says that it doesn't allow POST requests.

Comment: Change your `$.post` to `$.get` and see if it works.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see that. I'm going to edit and post the headers for the get.  Thanks.

Comment: Changing $.post to $.get doesnt make it work.  Note both ways work when running from the local file system, but neither work when using a local web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to anyone who runs into this.  It took me about a day to figure it out.  First off Blender was right about the POST requests, I changed them to GET requests.

Secondly the issue, as I found out lied not within my code, but with IIS 7.5.  It does not come with json as a predefined MIME type.  Here are the steps in order to solve this.

1)Make sure you are running IIS 7.5.

2)Open the IIS Services Manager.

3)Open up MIME Types

4)Add a new MIME type

5) There are two fields to fill out.

File Name Extension: **JSON**

MIME Type: **application/json**

After that it should work.